# Не работает appendСhild

Tags: javascript

При выполнении данного кода, страница виснет:

```
function scandiver(){
  for(var i = 0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++){
    if(document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].id.search(/div\d/i)>=0){
      var newelem = document.createElement("div");
      newelem.innerHTML=24;
      newelem.className="elemspiska";
      document.getElementById("spisokdiv").appendChild(newelem);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Не существует элемента с `id = "spisokdiv"`

Comment: Убедитесь, что код выполняется после готовности DOM. Например, выполнив его в коллбэке eventListener'а "DOMContentLoaded".

Comment: код выполняется по нажатию клавиши , такой элемент есть

Comment: @GsD ну, значит нет. Возможно, у вас `#spisokdiv` тоже генерируется каким-то событием, которое на момент выполнения этого еще не произошло. Ну либо просто банально неправильно указан ID. Или элемент не находится на странице по какой-то другой причине.

Comment: @GsD попробуйте вывести (console.log) этот элемент, увидите (скорее всего), что он будет равен undefined. Тут проблема точно не в appendChild().

Comment: я вставил вызов скриптов в конец боди , отдельно он работает , однако при исполнении функции в которой он находится страница виснет.

Comment: @GsD "отдельно он работает" - работает часть кода, приведенная в вопросе? Или вместе с обработчиками, про которые речь шла выше? Приведите более полный пример, потому что этот не является самодостаточным, здесь упущены строки, в которых, вероятно, проблема и заключена.

Comment: отдельно работает та часть кода которую я показывал ранее

Comment: @GsD отлично, а теперь добавьте в вопрос ошибку, которая получается при исполнении кода, *приведенного в вопросе*.

Comment: ошибки нету, страница просто виснет, на вкладке написано "страница не отвечает"

Comment: @GsD такое поведение обычно бывает, когда цикл не может завершиться, или его выполнение занимает больше времени, чем разрешено браузером. Вероятно, стоит вынести получение списка div'ов (getElementsByTagName) в отдельную переменную, чтобы этот поиск происходил лишь раз.

Comment: @GsD а вообще в идеале - использовать специальные методы, предназначенные для поиска элементов, а не "фильтровать" элементы, как это делаете вы.

Comment: @GsD чисто интереса ради, сколько (примерно) у вас таких элементов на странице?

Comment: изначально их 10 но они увеличиваются и вызывается эта функция

Comment: @GsD вероятно, в этом и кроется решение. Ради эксперимента, попробуйте запустить бесконечный цикл. Если поведение страницы будет такое же, значит вам нужно срочно избавляться от этой ужасной логики поиска (фильтрации) и писать нормальную (хотя это нужно делать в любом случае).

Comment: @GsD и для этого вам лучше переформулировать вопрос. Причину неработоспособности вы уже выяснили, теперь узнайте, как сделать лучше. Заголовком вопроса сделайте что-то вроде "Как найти на странице X элементы и произвести с ними Y манипуляции".

Answer (score 0):

Сделал в 2 прохода

```
function scandiver(){
        var divelementsid = [];
        var sch = 0;
        for(var i = 0;i<document.getElementsByTagName("div").length;i++){
                var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].id;
                if(div.search(/div\d/i)>=0){
                    divelementsid[sch++]=div;
                }   
    }

        for(var k =0;k<divelementsid.length;k++){
            var newelem = document.createElement("div");
            newelem.innerHTML="123";
            document.getElementById("spisokdiv").appendChild(newelem);

        }


    }
```